# E2E rails test through async job and post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I have a rails route that kicks off an async job thats supposed to post data somewhere when it finishes.

I would love to be able to test this method end to end, ensuring that the job completes and that it sends off a post to the url it's supposed to.

But I'm a little confused on what the best way to do this is. Some posts say that it is a fool's errand to try and test this end to end, and that I should test pieces individually. Others think integration testing is the only way to be sure.

Should I create some kind of listener to catch the post after its been sent out? Should I stub the http get? Or is the whole thing really truly a fools errand?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me it looks like you need two tests.

1. for the route to check if the job was scheduled
2. for the job to test if it executes correctly

For the network calls checks, I like to use [VCR](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/docs) so that I'm sure the call is correct and no additional requests were made.